# Error using Git in Visual Studio 2013 during merge

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have created a project using Git for version control. I have 3 branches (`Master`, `dev` and `hotFixes`).

I needed to make some changes in a C# function that use my program. I did the change inside my `hotFixes` branch. Then I executed the commands:

```
git add *
git commit -m "Fixes"
```

After that, from Visual Studio I used the Merge button:

[image]

But Visual Studio send me the next error:

[image: Visual Studio error: 1 conflict prevents checkout]

I already knew that would be a conflict, but now I wanted to compare the file that make the "conflict" in both branches (`dev` and `hotFixes`) inside Visual Studio to modify adapt the file that is in the `dev` branch in order to do the commit.

Does anyone know how can I do that? Or is there another alternative?

Comment: Did you try using the merge from inside visual studio?

Comment: Yes, in fact I use the merge from Visual Studio

Comment: Does the Solution Explorer mark the file(s) that have the conflict? You can then edit the file to resolve the conflict then re-commit the file.

Comment: you said you used git merge  in your question. You didn't say you used the merge button. iirc vs only supports merging in vs if you use the merge button (not 100% though)

Comment: Sorry, I've already modified the question. Thanks.

Comment: oh, your current branch is hotfixes. Switch to the dev (target) branch. And then do the merge.  Since the target branch gets a conflict, it can't be checked out. You have to start in the target branch.

Comment: In fact, I've  already done that switch in both sides (hotFixes -> dev and dev -> hotFixes) and the problem is still showing. I could merge only from git bash. When I executed the command, Visual Studio updated my file Class. Thats the only way I found to do the merge.